# Script Manager preventing master page menu

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written an aspx page in c# that uses a master page for a menu. On the child page, I have a scriptmanager control with an update panel. Everything works fine but the master page menu is displayed as a table instead of the menu format. Once the scriptmanager is removed from the child page, the menu is restored.The scriptmanger code is the first item under the content2 section.

```
<asp:Content ID = "Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID = "MainContent" runat="server">
     <h1> Test page 1</h1>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" />
<ContentTemplate>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your master page at the top try this:

```
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </asp:ScriptManager> // remove this script manager if you have included script manager in your other page.
// do other stuff.
</form>
</body>
```

For separate pages include your master file and try this:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/yourmasterfile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="yourfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="yourproject.yourfile" culture="auto"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterPageContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager> // remove this script manager if you have included script manager in master page
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePannel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
     // do your stuff here
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I would like to keep the scriptmanager separate from the master page if possible as I will need to change other pages then since it will complain about 'one script manager per page". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thank you!!